# Shade area between circle subpath and path

Tags: metapost

I want to shade the area between the arc and the subpath. I tried using `buildcycle` with no result. How should I do?

```
\starttext
\startuseMPgraphic{name}
draw fullcircle scaled 4cm;
path q; q := subpath (0, 5) of fullcircle scaled 4cm; drawarrow q;
path p[];
p1 = subpath (5, 8) of fullcircle scaled 4cm;
p2 = (cosd 225, sind 225)*2cm -- (cosd 0, sind 0)*2cm;
p3 = buildcycle(p1, p2);
filldraw p3 withcolor green;
draw p1; draw p2;
\stopuseMPgraphic
\useMPgraphic{name}
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `buildcycle` here.  Since all you are doing is closing the arc path, you can just use `-- cycle` like this:

```
\starttext
\startuseMPgraphic{name}
    path C, q, area; 
    C = fullcircle scaled 4cm;
    q = subpath (0, 5) of C; 
    area = subpath (5, 8) of C -- cycle;
    fill area withcolor 1/2[green, white];
    draw area;
    drawarrow q;
\stopuseMPgraphic
\useMPgraphic{name}
\stoptext
```

[image]

- *why* `buildcycle` does not work here is an interesting question.  It is not because the two paths do not overlap -- you would get an error message in that case -- I think it is because when `buildcycle` looks for the intersection, it finds the same point both times, so the area that it fills is just a point (so you can't see it).
- compiling the OP code with plain `mpost` produces this PostScript output (in part)

  ```
  0 1 0 setrgbcolor
  newpath -40.08661 -40.08762 moveto
  -40.08652 -40.08739 lineto
  closepath
  gsave fill grestore stroke
  ```

  which confirms my theory that `buildcycle` has created a very tiny closed path, which is invisible in the output.

Comment: Is an answer possible using Tikz?